# What is the output of Spark MLLIB LDA topicsmatrix?

Tags: python, apache-spark-mllib, bayesian, lda

The output of `LDAModel.topicsMatrix()` is unclear to me.
I think I understand the concept of LDA and that each topic is represented by a distribution over terms.

In the `LDAModel.describeTopics()` it is clear (I think):
The highest sum of likelihoods of words of a sentence per topic, indicates the evidence of this tweet belonging to a topic.
With n topics, the output of `describeTopics()` is a n times m matrix where m stands for the size of the vocabulary. The values in this matrix are smaller or equal to 1.

However in the `LDAModel.topicsMatrix()`, I have no idea what I am looking at. The same holds when reading the documentation.
The matrix is a m times n matrix, the dimensions have changed and the values in this matrix are larger than zero (and thus can take the value 2, which is not a probability value). What are these values? The occurrence of this word in the topic perhaps?

How do I use these values do calculate the distance of a sentence to a topic?

Comment: I could not find out this from documentation either, but it looks like these are parameters of the Dirichlet distribution that describe the multionomial distribution of words—topics. This makes sense in terms of dimensions, and in terms of observed values. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) notation this is called $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

i think the matrix is m*n m is the words number and n is the topic number

Comment: val topics = ldaModel.topicsMatrix
    for (topic <- Range(0, 3)) {
      print("Topic " + topic + ":")
      for (word <- Range(0, ldaModel.vocabSize)) { print(" " + topics(word, topic)); }
      println()
    }             maybe you can check by this

Comment: You edit your answer and add code as part of the answer instead of adding it to comment.